# No llegan los datos a través de una petición API con el método post al backend, pero sí funciona con Insomnia/Postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, express

Estoy intentando realizar una petición POST a una API que tengo alojada en el backend. El código del Backend lo he probado con el software de Insomnia para ver que está bien, y así es. Sin embargo, al hacer la misma petición desde cliente, me llega un objeto vacío al backend.

El controlador del backend es tal que así:

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt-nodejs");
const User = require("./../models/user");

function signUp (req, res) {
  const user = new User();

  console.log(req.body);
  const { email, username, password, repeatPassword } = req.body;
  user.email = email;
  user.username = username;
  user.active = false;
  user.thumb = "";

  if (!password || !repeatPassword) {
    res.status(404).send({message: "Las contraseñas son oblitagorias"});
  } else {
    if (password !== repeatPassword) {
      res.status(402).send({message: "Las contraseñas no son iguales"});
    } else {
      bcrypt.hash(password, null, null, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({message: "Error al encriptar la constraseña"});
        } else {
          user.password = hash;

          //guardamos en mongodb
          user.save((err, userStored) => {
            if (err) {
              res.status(500).send({message: "Error del servidor" + err})
            } else {
              if (!userStored) {
                res.status(404).send({message: "Error al crear el usuario"});
              } else {
                res.status(200).send({user: userStored})
              }
            }
          });
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Y desde cliente hago la petición de esta forma:

```
export function signUpApi(data) {
    console.log("el dato que llega: ", data);

    const uri = `${basePath}/${baseVersion}/sign-up`; // sería http://localhost:5000/api/v1/sign-up
    const params = {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        header: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    };

    console.log("params", params);

    fetch(uri, params)
        .then( response => {
            console.log(response)
        });
}
```

El objeto `params` de la petición es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el controlador del backend me da una respuesta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Simplemente no estas llegando porque tu ruta esta mal especificada en el front, o se llama de otra forma en el back... donde configuras las rutas (con expressjs supongo)

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera El backend funciona bien con Insomnia, tiene que ser algo relacionado con la parte de cliente entiendo, pero el endpoint es correcto. He visto que hay mucha gente con este problema pero o es porque no enviaban los datos con `JSON.stringify()` o porque les faltaba el `body-parser`, que si no me equivoco ya está deprecated.

Comment: Es que es raro, porque te esta indicando que no encuentra el endpoint, no pasa por un tema de datos. Por eso te menciono lo de las rutas... Podrías incluir en donde configuras tus rutas?